# I'm getting the multi part identifier could not be bound when executing my statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this in SQL Server:

```
select 
    r.DATE_, r.SAL
from 
    RES r 
inner join 
    (select top 1 * 
     from BAD 
     where SAL= RES.SAL 
     order by bad_id asc) b on r.DATE_ = b.DATE_
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Msg 4104
>   The multi-part identifier RES.SAL could not be bound

Best regards

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected output.

Comment: You need to use the `r` alias

Comment: You can't reference objects outside of a subquery in a `JOIN` (or lateral subquery); you would need to do the reference in the `ON` outside of the subquery. As Gordon has pointed out, however, you can use `CROSS APPLY` which turns the lateral subquery into a correlated subquery.

Comment: @kobik that won't help here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cross apply` instead of `join`:

```
select r.DATE_, r.SAL
from RES r cross apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from BAD b
      where r.SAL = b.SAL 
      order by b.bad_id asc
     ) b 
where r.DATE_ = b.DATE_;
```

However, I think the logic is more clearly written as:

```
select r.DATE_, r.SAL
from RES r 
where r.DATE_ = (select top (1) b.DATE_
                 from BAD b
                 where r.SAL = b.SAL 
                 order by b.bad_id asc
                ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows too

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT r.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.SAL ORDER BY b.bad_id DESC) AS rn
FROM dbo.RES r
INNER JOIN dbo.BAD  b ON r.SAL= b.SAL 
)
SELECT r.DATE_, r.SAL
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```